# Writing to existing blank spaced binary file in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write to an existing blank spaced binary file of 1 MB in size via C++, at a particular position.

```
ofstream of( filename, ofstream::binary );
of.seekp(1600, of.beg);
of.write(arr, 1024);
of.close();
```

The blank file is created by writing this buffer to file before:

```
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(size);     
memset(buffer, ' ', size);
```

But this code just truncates the entire blank space file of 1MB and writes this 1KB content and the size of the file becomes 1KB.

Tried using the `app` as well as `ate` mode too. When I tried `app` mode like this:

```
ofstream of( filename, ofstream::binary | ofstream::app );
of.seekp(1600, of.beg);
of.write(arr, 1024);
of.close();
```

It adds the content to the end of the file. Thus the file becomes of size 1MB+1KB.

What I am trying to do is overwrite a 1KB data(at present it is blank space) in the file with some data. So that it won't change the file size or any other data.

Where am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: I can't be the only person that is curious what a "blank spaced binary file" *is*. I just can't be...

Comment: sorry if i used the wrong term. I included the code above. Please check

Comment: Ah.. ok. so it is a file that leads with a predetermined bytes equivalent to a platform-dependant space (ascii 0x20, for example, or ebcdic 0x40). That makes a bit more sense. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find that [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) (there is a similar mechanism for Windows) can be very convenient when reading/updating data at random offsets in an existing file. IMHO code which uses it tends to be more legible than code that seeks around using streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ofstream of( filename, ofstream::binary | ofstream::in | ofstream::out)
```

to open the binary file for update.

See C++11 Table 123 - File Open Modes (in 27.9.1.4/3):

```
Table 132 — File open modes

 ios_base flag combination          stdio 
binary  in   out  trunc  app       equivalent
---------------------------------------------------
              +                      "w"    truncate/create for writing
              +           +          "a"    append - writes automatically seek to EOF
                          +          "a"    
              +     +                "w"    
        +                            "r"    open for read
---------------------------------------------------
        +     +                      "r+"   open for update (reading and writing)
        +     +     +                "w+"   truncate/create for update
        +     +           +          "a+"   open or create for update - writes seek to EOF
        +                 +          "a+"
---------------------------------------------------
  +           +                      "wb"   All same as above, but in binary mode
  +           +           +          "ab"
  +                       +          "ab"
  +           +     +                "wb"
  +     +                            "rb"
---------------------------------------------------
  +     +     +                      "r+b"
  +     +     +     +                "w+b"
  +     +     +           +          "a+b"
  +     +                 +          "a+b"
```

Comment: Because if you don't the file will be truncated.

Comment: Michale Burr, that was brilliant! :)